# Backup Spanning Multiple DVD-Rs

Tags: backup, dvd-burning

Is there anything built into OS X Lion that allows you to have a backup that spans multiple disks?

I've got about 80GB of files pulled down from our web servers that I'd like to get put on DVD-Rs, and would rather not have to manually fit dirs ontop the discs.

Anything built into OS X or freeware to do this?

Comment: Hard drives are pretty inexpensive these days. You might be a lot happier picking up a $60 HDD that you can re-use :)

Comment: Nope. Want a DVD-R backup too.

Already have it on a hard drive. Looking to have a backup in another medium that can't be overwritten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is nothing built in

Roxio Toast has a data disc spanning feature, for large files it will split to fit, or you can opt not to split files for easier recovery.

Another solution would be to use an archiving (read:compression) utility that will allow you to compress to multiple archives of a fixed size, say 4.7Gb, the down side of which is that you will lose everything if one disc is unreadable